# How do I properly reference inline functions in ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, paperjs

So I am trying to animate some items on a canvas using paper.js. Currently I have this (some items are cut out for brevity):

```
class Sprite {
    constructor() {
        animate();
    }
    animate() {
        paper.view.attach('frame', function (event) {
            if (event.count < destinationX * tileWidth) {
                //animate stuff
            } else {
                //exit here
                paper.view.detach('frame', this);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The issue is that the animation ends up starting, but never actually stops. I also tried

```
animate() {
        paper.view.attach('frame', doAnimation);
        function doAnimation(event){
            if (event.count < destinationX * tileWidth) {
                //animate stuff
            } else {
                //exit here
                paper.view.detach('frame', doAnimation);
            }
        }
    }
```

But that never actually causes the animation to attach to the view and it never starts. What syntax should I be using here to get everything to properly link up?

Comment: You are doing it the same way as in ES5.

Comment: @FelixKling, ES5 doesn't have the class syntax though, so the behavior of `this` changes. That's why I can't get it to exit I think.

Comment: @Alex: The behaviour of `this` inside that `function` does not have anything to do with the class syntax. Do you have some working ES5 code? What is the error you get from your second code? It looks that it should work no different (apart from the exit case).

Comment: The only "change" to `this` in ES6 is with arrow functions. But you are not using any arrow functions here. It seems you expect `this` to refer to the function in the first example. That is not and has never been the case. I'm not familiar with paper.js but the second example looks technically correct. You have to give the function a name in order to reference it. You could do that as well in the first example.

Comment: If the first version never stops and the second version never starts (or doesn't seem to start), then chances are that there is something wrong with your condition (or calculations).